# Why are there so many tty files in the /dev directory?

Tags: linux, hardware, ram, busybox

It is confusing that there are so many `tty` files in the `/dev` directory...

[image]

By the way, what does each file in `/dev` stand for? Do they stand for physical devices which are part of my Android device? For example, which file stands for the raw storage device in the `/dev` directory?

Answer (score 2):

That's because there are so many devices available. Entries in `/dev` are not restricted to *physical* devices, but also include *logical* ones. You just named one: TTY. You don't really think you've got 63 "connectors" somewhere to attach keyboards etc. to? Also, `/dev/random` is nothing physical, but rather "software" (a random-number generator provided by the system itself). Same applies to things like `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`, and several others.

For more/deeper details, you might refer to following articles:

- [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html)
- [Device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) (Wikipedia) -- recommended for this topic, as it explicitly included [Pseudo-devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Pseudo-devices)
- [Linux System Administrator's Guide - The / dev directory](http://linux.about.com/od/lsa_guide/a/gdelsa18.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Not all devices at /dev are physical, some of them are logical and may be temporary needed by kernel/software (and some of them are symlinks, like log_modem -> /dev/ttyACM2).
And, as I see, you have default linux tty count. It's not used (reserved and may be used), but it's no problem.